# Type mismatch error and object defined error?

Tags: excel, vba

Type mismatch error is coming in this code only at "aStr". But "bStr" is taking string value. Also at the condition of if statement I'm getting object defined error.

```
Dim i, a, b, rowInt As Integer
Dim colC, colE, colA, colG, aStr, bStr As String
Dim cellRef1, cellRef2, cellRef3 As String
Dim delRef1, delRef2 As String

rowInt = Evaluate("LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""""),ROW(A:A))") - 11

Sheets("Orders").Select

colA = "A"
colC = "C"
colE = "E"
colG = "G"

i = 1
     Do
          Sheets("Orders").Select
          a = i + 10
          b = i + 11
          aStr = a
          bStr = b
          cellRef1 = colC + aStr
          cellRef2 = colC + bStr
          cellRef3 = colE + aStr
          cellRef4 = colE + bStr
          delRef1 = colA + bStr
          delRef2 = colG + bStr
          Range("D1").Value = i
          If Sheets("Orders").Range(cellRef1).Text = Sheets("Orders").Range(cellRef2).Text Then
               Range(cellRef3).Value = Range(cellRef3).Value + Range(cellRef4).Value
               Range("" & delRef1 & ":" & delRef2 & "").Delete Shift:=xlUp
               rowInt = rowInt - 1
               i = i + 1
          Else
               i = i + 1
          End If
     Loop While i = rowInt

End Sub
```

Comment: In `Dim colC, colE,...,aStr, bStr As String` the `As String` _only_ applies to the last variable declared. it does not apply to all variables declared on that line. So all the other variables are just `Variant`

Comment: If you use the VBA debugger, you may see that `cellRef1` may not have the value you expect.

Comment: Bit hard for us to work through that, you will have to do some debugging yourself. The concatenation operator is `&`, not `+`.

Comment: Yes, this solved my error. Thank you!

Comment: Using `Integer` rather than `Long` is pointless at best and harmful at worst. Under the hood, an `Integer` will be stored as a `Long` anyway, so all you get for using `Integer` is the possibility of overflowing the variable prior to the number of rows in a spreadsheet. With 16-bit Windows, there might have been a point for it in the 1990s, but not today. Also, you might benefit from reading [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4996248)

Comment: A lot of that code looks superfluous.

Comment: @SJR, I believe `+` works fine as long as both operands are strings.